# Hosting multiple apps with different platforms on azure

Tags: azure

I would like to find the easiest solution/service to host multiple apps.  We are an R&D shop and we will need to utilize different technology stacks but they should be limited to .NET, Java, Python, and NodeJS.  Is there a prepackages service that can host all?  It appears when I try and use Web App in Azure I can only select from Python or Java and I can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Web App which is the PaaS offer on Azure to host your solutions.

However, you'll need one to each programming language. If you want everything in the same "box" then you'll need a virtual machine but you'll be responsible to maintain / manage your VM and also runtimes for your applications.

Comment: I guess that was my hope that I would not have to use a VM.  No way to use multiple programming languages on one PaaS instance?